# How to get the image src which is dynamically created

Tags: jquery, html

I am making gallery application.In which i am displaying some images from a folder to **index.html** page by fetching image path from database and appending this path into a div Dynamically.
my image folder name is **tutor_images**

Here is the **index.html** code where i am appending the images

```
<div id="allTutors" class="slider filtering scrollpoint sp-effect5" >
<div class="lists">
</div>
</div>
```

Now this **js code** is appending the imaged  path to div.its working perfectly

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'php/all-tutors.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(data){
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(result, function(key, value){
                $.each(value, function(k,v){
                    if (k === 'image_path') {
                        var gh = $("<img id='tutorImg' src="+v.slice(3)+">");
                        $('#allTutors .lists:first')
                        .clone()
                        .append("<img id='tutorImg' src="+v.slice(3)+"><button id='viewTutor' class='btn btn-primary'>View Profile</button>")
                        .appendTo($('#allTutors')); 
                    }
                    if (k === 'name') {
                        $('#allTutors .lists:first')
                        .clone()
                        .append("<h4 id='tutorList'>"+v+"</h4><br/>")
                        .appendTo($('#allTutors'));
                    }

                });
            });
        }
    })

    });
});
```

Now , **My problem** is:

i want that when i click the specific button next to the image than i get the **src** of  that **images**  .

please help me .!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to listen to `#allTutors` due to dynamic content

```js
$('#allTutors').on('click','button',function(){
  img = $(this).prev('img');
  if(img.length > 0){
    alert(img.attr('src'));
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="allTutors">
  <img src="image/src.jpg" alt="image" />
  <button>get src</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it that i generally apply is
when generating each div, give it's id an index.

For example

```
 <div id="allTutors">
   <img id = 'tutorImage1' src="image/src.jpg" alt="image" />
   <button onclick = 'getTheSrcForThisOne(1)'>get src</button>
 </div>

 <script>
      function getTheSrcForThisOne(which){
         console.log(getElementById("tutorImage"+which).src);
      }

 </script>
```

Just add the id to the element at the same time you're adding the src. Then add the id to the button aswell.
Simple and lets you interact with each one and know which one is being acted on.

### Edit

Better yet, make the image a button itself.

```
 <div id="allTutors">
   <img src="image/src.jpg" alt="image" onclick = 'getMySRC(this)'/>
 </div>

 <script>
      function getMySRC(forWho){
         console.log(forWho.src);
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by replacing the src attribute (i dont advise that):

```
<img id="yourImageId" src="assets/img/image01.jpg" alt="..." />
<button id="yourButtonId">NEXT</button>

<script src="jquery.js></script>
<script>
$( "#yourButtonId" ).click(function() {
   #( "#yourImageId" ).attr("src").replace("image01.jpg", "image02.jpg");
});
<script>
```

or you can code in html a list of images all of them with "display: none;" and every time you click next, you change the actual pic to display none and the next one to display block.